# How to create restriction sign up to email addresses ending in "@domain.com"

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Other email address should not be able to register on my website registration page except for emails ending in "@domain.com"

Comment: Why is this question tagged ".htaccess"? This certainly is nothing that should get validated on protocol level but in your application logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your theme functions.php file. Just change the domain.com to something else like gmail.com,outlook.com etc

```
// Custom domain registration only

function custom_domain_email($login, $email, $errors ){
 $accepted_domains_emails = array("domain.com");// allowed domains
 $valid = false; // sets default validation to false
 foreach( $accepted_domains_emails as $d ){
  $d_length = strlen( $d );
  $accepted_email_domain = strtolower( substr( $email, -($d_length), $d_length));
 if( $accepted_email_domain == strtolower($d) ){
  $valid = true;
  break;
 }
 }
 // Show error message
 if( $valid === false ){

$errors->add('domain_whitelist_error',__( 'Registration is only allowed from domains.com domain only.' ));
 }
}
add_action('register_post', 'custom_domain_email',10,3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use a regular expression and match the given email address against it. Here is a simple demonstration using four addresses and deciding for each, whether it is accepted or rejected:

```
<?php
$emailAddresses = [
  "personA@good.com ",
  "   personB@good.com",
  "personC@bad.com", 
  "personD@ivalid",
  "personE"
];

array_walk($emailAddresses, function($emailAddress) {
  var_dump(preg_match('/@good\.com$/', trim($emailAddress)) ? "accepted" : "rejected");
});
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(8) "accepted"
string(8) "accepted"
string(8) "rejected"
string(8) "rejected"
string(8) "rejected"
```

So all you actually need is that command:

> preg_match('/@domain.com$/', trim($emailAddress))